# When writing a single package meant to be used as a command, which is idiomatic: name all identifiers as private or name all identifiers as public?

Tags: go, private, public, idioms

In Go, public names start with an upper case letter and private names start with a lower case letter.

I'm writing a program that is not library and is a single package. Is there any Go idiom that stipulates whether my identifiers should be all public or all private? I do not plan on using this package as a library or as something that should be imported from another Go program.

I can't think of any reason why I'd want a mixture. It "feels" like going all private is the proper choice.

---

I don't think I got any concrete answer, but Nate was closest with telling me to think of "exporting vs non-exporting" instead of "public and private".

This leads me to believe that not exporting anything is the best approach. In the worst case scenario, if I end up importing code from my application in another package, I will have to rethink what should be exported and what shouldn't be. Which is a good thing IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are attempting to adjust your mindset to be more Go idiomatic, you should stop thinking of variables, functions, and methods as public or private.  The more accurate term is exported or not exported.  It definitely has a more C like feel to it.

As others have stated exporting really isn't needed for application program code.  If for organizational reasons you decide to break your program up into packages, you could use sub-packages.  At work we've decided to do just this.  We have:

```
projectgopath/src/projectname
                  projectname/subcomponent1
                  projectname/subcomponent2
```

So far I am really liking this structure.  It aids in separation of concerns, but does not go to the extent of making a package outside of the main project.  The intent is clear.  The sub-package's intended use is for this program only...

The new go build and go install commands seem to deal very well with it.  We group components together in packages and expose only the necessary bits via exports.

Answer (score 2):

In the described situation both approaches are equally valid, so it's more or less a matter of personal preferences. In my case I'm using camelCase identifiers for package main, mostly out of habit.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of my go files started their life in isolated commands and were moved to packages as they could be reused by a few commands around the same topic.

I think you should make private all that couldn't possibly be called from elsewhere (supposing one day you make it an importable package) and make public the big functions that can be understood from elsewhere (if any) and structs fields when they are orthogonal (I mean when a change of the value of one field doesn't break the consistency of the struct value).